# Is redis required even when working with pusher?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5.8, pusher

I have created a chat application on Laravel using Vue and Pusher. I would like to know if that is enough for production server where a lot of people will chat with each other. Or do I have to implement redis as well for server load management?

Comment: You has to run a performance test  to ensure the result, jmeter is the tool and easy to go.

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thank you.